# GeoServer Error decoding CRS: Error in "PROJECTION": No transform for classification

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

What I would like to do is to project world map from EPSG:4326 to other ones in geoserver ,special for the Esri EPSG world projection methods.
GeoServer has so many EPSG codes in the demo/srslist, but seems most of them do not work.

For example,from EPSG 4326 to 54052 `PROJCRS["World_Goode_Homolosine_Land"]`, I put the `gt-epsg-extension-23.2.jar` which mainly support the Esri EPSGs to the GeoServer lib path，it should have done for it's projecion, but nothing happens.

So how to make GeoServer support the Esri world map projection, like "World_Goode_Homolosine_Land" 54052, "World_Bonne" 54024 or "World_Winkel" 54019? GeoTools maybe supported the Esri EPSGs, does some errors happen in the GeoServer inside?

Comment: Please [request that your multiple accounts be merged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20two%20accounts,that%20you%20own%20both%20accounts.). This will permit you to edit your own post.

Answer (score 2):

[GeoTools](https://geotools.org) (the underlying library that GeoServer is built with) has [supported Winkel Tripel projections since version 2.7](https://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2011/03/), but this seems to be only World Winkel I (ESRI:54018).

So you would need to implement the projection for Winkel II as a new projection and add that code to GeoTools for this to be used in GeoServer.